# Imagemagick Text Clipping Path

Tags: php, imagick, clipping

I'd like to have a text clipped along a clipping path in Imagemagick. I have found a solution using [pdflib](http://www.pdflib.com/fileadmin/pdflib/Cookbook/pdf/text_with_image_clipping_path.pdf) (see use case 2) but want to have it purely in php/Imagick.
Can someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: I see ways to use bounding boxes and text paths but nothing as specific as the example you have. I suspect that you could get close by defining the region and either warping your text or bounding it inside of a complex region.

Comment: Could you be more precise on the bounding boxes, please?

Comment: http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/text/ - about 3/4 of the way down there is discussion about bounding boxes and text.. and how it may overflow.

Comment: Can you change your comment to an answer? It is not precisely what I was looking after but has indeed led me in the right direction. I'd therefore like to accept this as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [here](http://imagemagick.org/Usage/text) - about 3/4 of the way down there is discussion about bounding boxes and text.. and how it may overflow.